# GPO to deny removable disk access not being enforced after reboot

Tags: windows-7, usb, group-policy

I am working on an issue for a small network, in which one of the requirements is to deny read/write access to removable disks for regular user accounts (admin is permitted).

I have noticed that if there is a USB stick plugged in when the machine boots, the USB will sometimes be accessible when logged in with a regular user account. This doesn't seem to be consistent, sometimes it works and others it doesn't. However, in testing I was able to reproduce this without having the admin account logged on prior to the reboot. In other words, a user could bring a stick to the machine, plug it in during boot, and get access to it.

Is there anything I can do to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Which exact methods are you implementing to try and block them?

Comment: Via local computer policy - Removable disks: Deny read access and Deny write access are set for Non-administrators. Have also tried the same setting on a GPO linked to the users OU (not enforced), and the default domain policy GPO (enforced). Winning GPO is local policy, unless those settings are set on the default domain policy, but it has the same behavior regardless of where I set it.